# html to excel problem!

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I am printing excel like this:

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".str_replace(' ', '_', $title).".xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

The content is plain html. The problem, when I download this, I get an initial confirmation box written

`The file you are trying to open 'File_name.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verified that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?`

When I do 'yes', I get this. Bit strange, any input here friends please ?

[image]

Comment: In which language asp.net,php,asp,cold fusion ...etc

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are "printing" this xls file from. And from what I think I understand, are you simply writing an HTML file that has the extension xls?

Comment: @geek, it's php. @keepitreal89, yes, it's data fetched from mysql using php, and then displaying using a html table.

Comment: Don't use two different content types (the browser only expects one, correct content type header)... stick with application/vnd.ms-excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one suddenly got solved, I don't know how.

This is what I did. I copied and pasted codes of a different page where the excel thing was working. Then, I changed the variables manually to adapt this with the 2nd page.

After some hit and try, it suddenly worked.

Thanks for all the answers anyway.

PS. By solved, I mean that excel is not crushing anymore, though I am still getting the confirm box about incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is pretty strange. I doubt this will help, but try renaming it to .xlsx. It might just be that it's not getting the proper (newer) file extension.

Comment: Thanks Rev. Well the idea was to use .xls, so that even people who are using the older version MS Office can open the file.

Comment: The file isn't an Excel file though, so using the .xls (or .xlsx) ending is basically lying to Excel. Fortunately, most versions of Excel are used to this, and will import HTML anyway, even if it's from a file with an xls extension. But you should stick with the correct content type heading.

Comment: @Mark Baker, how do you generate excel (or rtf or pdf) files generally?

Comment: @Jeremy - personally, I generate the real thing, in the appropriate file format, so if I'm generating an Excel file, I generate a BIFF8 (xls) or Office Open XML (xlsx) formatted file, and then match the headers to the format

Answer (score 0):

I always use content type = "application/ms-excel"

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that does the same thing; it sets `ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"` and it works correctly (you still get the warning about that it's in the wrong format, but it opens after that).

I suspect the problem is not the content type, but the actual html content you are sending.  Can you post an example of the file you are sending that causes the error?

Comment: Well @toby, you are right here. Because I'm using the same structure to create a different excel file which is working nicely (I still get that warning, but Excel doesn't crash). In this particular thing, Excel crashes once, and when it opens again after (automatically, since recover checkbox is ticked), Excel doesn't crashes a second time.